# Getting 'ímplicit declaration of function' error while adding a system call in Linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I am trying to add a new system call that displays some information about currently running processes in the system. I created a new struct named *proc_info_struct* that contains parts of the process information I want to display. Here is the proc_info_struct code defined in the *procinfo.h* header file:

```
#include <linux/types.h>

struct proc_info_struct
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid_t parn_pid;
    pid_t gid;
    unsigned long user_time;
    unsigned long sys_time;
    long state;
    unsigned long long sched_avg_running;
    unsigned int time_slice;
    unsigned int policy;
    unsigned long num_cxs;

    int num_children;
    char* prog;
};
```

In the system call method(shown below), I try to check if the process specified exists or not by using the kill() function defined in signal.h using [this](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill) link as a reference. Here is the code which I use to get the process information:

```
#include <linux/procinfo.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/errno.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/linkage.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <asm-generic/current.h>
#include <linux/signal.h>

void fill_proc_info(struct proc_info_struct *proc_info, struct task_struct *task)
{
    int num_ch = 0;
    struct list_head* list;
    proc_info->pid = task->pid;
    proc_info->parn_pid = (task->parent)->pid;
    proc_info->gid = task->tgid;
    proc_info->user_time = task->utime;
    proc_info->sys_time = task->stime;
    proc_info->state = task->state;
    proc_info->sched_avg_running = task->cputime_expires.sum_exec_runtime; // Average scheduled running time;
    proc_info->policy = task->policy;
    proc_info->time_slice = task->rt.time_slice;
    proc_info->num_cxs = (task->nvcsw) + (task->nivcsw); // Nnumber of context switches(both voluntary and involuntary)

    list_for_each(list, &task->children)
    {
        num_ch++;
    }
    proc_info->num_children = num_ch;
    proc_info->prog = task->comm;
}


asmlinkage long sys_getprocinfo(pid_t pid, struct proc_info_struct *proc)
{
    struct task_struct *task;
    struct proc_info_struct *proc_info;

    if(pid)
    {
        // Current process
        task = get_current();
        fill_proc_info(proc_info, task);
    }
    else
    {
        int exists = 0; // Checks whether a process exists or not
        for_each_process(task)
        {
            if(task->pid = pid)
            {
                exists = 1;
            }
        }

        if(exists)
        {
            //task = find_task_by_vpid(pid);  we don't need this line now since the task has now been set in for_each_process

             fill_proc_info(proc_info, task);
        }
        else
        {
            printk("Process doesn't exist");
            return -ESRCH:
        }
    }

    if (copy_to_user(proc, proc_info, sizeof(proc_info)))
        return -EFAULT;
    return 1;
}
```

When I try to build the kernel by using 'make', I get the following error

[image: Error]

As it can be seen above, I have included the signal.h header in the line:

```
#include <linux/signal.h>
```

What am I missing here? How is there an alternative way I can check if a given process exists in the system by using its pid other than kill function?

---

Using the suggestions in the answer, I replaced the *kill* function call with *for_each_process* macro. Now it compiles successfully. I wrote a test code to test the system call. When I give a non-existing pid, the system call works correctly by displaying 'Process doesn't exist' in the kernel log. However, when I give an existing code, it raises the displays error in the kernel log:

> BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at (null)

**The test code**

```
int main()
{
    struct proc_info_struct *proc_info;
    pid_t pid = 0; // I tried
    /;

    syscall(314, pid, &proc_info);

    printf("Pid: %ld\nParent: %ld\nGid:%ld\nUtime: %lu\nSysTime:
        %d\nState: %lu\n,Time_Slice: %d\nPolicy: %d\nNum_CXS: %lu\nNumChild:
        %d\nProg: %s\n",proc_info->pid, proc_info->parn_pid, proc_info->gid,
        proc_info->user_time, proc_info->sys_time, proc_info->state, proc_info->time_slice,
        proc_info->policy, proc_info->num_cxs, proc_info->num_children, proc_info->prog);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As an aside: You *are* aware that procfs already makes most, if not all, of this information available?

Comment: I just realized that since you are inside the kernel you have no `kill` visible. Try killing the process with: `kill_proc_info(SIGKILL, SEND_SIG_PRIV, pid)`

Comment: @mziccard can you please elaborate on how I would you use kill_proc_info(SIGKILL, SEND_SIG_PRIV, pid) or give me a link I can refer to?

Comment: @avidProgrammer Have a look at `linux/sched.h`: several functions to send signals are defined and amongst them you can find `kill_proc_info`, `kill_pid_info` and `kill_pid`.  All three are implemented in `kernel/signal.c` and in general both `kill_proc_info` and `kill_pid` are wrappers of `kill_pid_info`. All tree functions are used around the kernel to kill processes.  With `kill_proc_info(SIGKILL, SEND_SIG_PRIV, pid)` you should be sending the `SIGKILL` signal to the process identified by `pid`. `SEND_SIG_PRIV` indicates that the sender is privileged (the kernel).

Comment: I actually don't want to kill processes, I want to send a kill signal with signal value of 0 so that it returns an error value if the process doesn't exist. Can kill_proc_info(SIGKILL, SEND_SIG_PRIV, pid) achieve the same result as kill(0, pid)? And also what are some possible values of SEND_SIG_PRIV paramater? I would appreciate it much if you could show me by example.

Comment: @avidProgrammer kill_proc_info(SIGKILL, SEND_SIG_PRIV, pid) is actually an example:) SIGKILL is a MACRO that you should have available including `sched.h`. `SEND_SIG_PRIV` is a MACRO as well defined in `sched.h` that identifies a privileged sender, and `pid` was intended to be the variable in your code. I understand now that you do not want to kill the process. Try to replace `SIGKILL` with `0`: `kill_proc_info(0, SEND_SIG_PRIV, pid)` and that _should_ achieve the same result as `kill(pid, 0)`. I am not totally sure of this as I have not tested it.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31015471/edit) (it covers program output as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Kernel code doesn't define user space functions, like `kill`.

For searching through processes, you can try `for_each_process` macro, defined in file *linux/sched.h*.

BTW, according to comments in your code, you used `find_task_by_vpid` for some purpose. This function just returns a task, which has a given pid. Why do you not want to use it? Also, you can investigate the implementation of the system call `kill`: how it searches needed task. This system call is defined in `kernel/signal.c` as `SYSCALL_DEFINE2(kill,...`.

Also note that searching task (in any form) and reading its fields should be performed within the `rcu_read_lock`/`rcu_read_unlock` critical section. This protects tasks lists from element destruction during a search.

Comment: Tsyvarev and @Vadim Stupakov, I edited the question using your answers. However, there is another error being raised.

Comment: Your forget `break;` in your search. Answer has been updated with other alternatives to search task.

Answer (score 1):

[Tsyvarev is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31015471/getting-%C3%ADmplicit-declaration-of-function-error-while-adding-a-system-call-in-l/31015843#31015843) right. The Linux kernel doesn't contain kill. But it contains [sys_kill](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/syscalls.h#L374).

Also, you can look on my [test project](https://github.com/Vadim-Stupakov/application-firewall-for-linux/blob/master/release/affl_process.c). There you can find the [affl_kill_process()](https://github.com/Vadim-Stupakov/application-firewall-for-linux/blob/master/release/affl_process.c#L351) function which kills a process.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
```

before all inclusions.